# slideUp does not work

Tags: jquery

I couldn't find the answer to this, though it seems simple. I have an element that when clicked makes an element slideDown.When this happens another element is added to the end that works like a link to slideUp the same content. So the slideDown works, but the slideUp doesn't. I've even just changed the slideUp to just show an alert, and it's not getting called. I'm going to have several of these on the page, so I need to call the "next" .hide-reveal div.

html:

```
<p class="read-more">read more link</p>
<div class="hide-reveal">
  <p> here is first para</p>
  <p> here is second para.</p>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.hide-reveal{
   display:none;
}
```

and the js:

```
$('.read-more').on('click',function(){
$(this).next('.hide-reveal').slideDown().after("<p class=\"read-less\">read less</p>");
});
$(".read-less").on('click',function(){
  alert("hi");
});
```

Why won't my second function work?

Comment: The event listener is not attaching to anything; it is being parsed when there are no `.read-less` elements on the page. Either add the event listener to the `.read-less` element when you make it, or use a document listener like so: `$(document).on('click', '.read-less', function(){ alert('hi'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.read-less` element is instantiated inside the onclick event attached to the `.read-more` element. You need to do this:

```js
$('.read-more').on('click',function(){
$(this).next('.hide-reveal').slideDown().after("<p class=\"read-less\">read less</p>");
$(".read-less").on('click',function(){
  alert("hi");
});
});
```

```css
.hide-reveal{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="read-more">read more link</p>
<div class="hide-reveal">
  <p> here is first para</p>
  <p> here is second para.</p>
</div>
```